# Updating Controlling Picklist with Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, picklist, field-dependencies

I've encountered a strange problem. I have 2 pick list fields, controller picklist and the dependent picklist. I'm trying to use process builder to update the controller picklist using a process builder but every time I set the dependency, the controlling picklist field is not available for update.

I haven't come across any articles showing why this strange behavior, anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 1):

Though I have an experience of updating controlling and dependent picklist values through Process Builder. Here I could suggest you to check.

1. User's profile should have field level security to those picklist fields.
2. If you are using recordtype, then user's profile should have access to the recordtype.
3. Values must be available to that recordtype.
4. User's profile should have assignment of controlling and dependent values.
5. Process builder must be activated.
6. Verify the debug log if any other process, workflows, triggers are getting fired for this update.

Comment: I'm using an admin profile so the issue is not permissions.  The Values are available for that record type but unfortunately. When I remove the field dependency, the process builder works perfectly.